# Does InnoDB ever release unused disk space?

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete, disk-space

A large MySQL association table with 500M rows recently ballooned into 1B rows due to a bug (now fixed). Disk usage went from ~130GB to 240GB.

Unfortunately there is not room on this server for any of the standard remedies (`OPTIMIZE` or `ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=InnoDB`, dump & rebuild, build into temporary table & rename & drop old table, etc.). I only have 50GB remaining.

Here's the question:

While I've successfully removed over 100M rows so far (1B down to 850M), disk usage has actually grown by 10GB (to 250GB). Yes, new records are also being added every second, but I'm deleting far faster than they are being added.

1. Will InnoDB ever release this space?
2. Why does the table disk usage
   grow, while I'm shrinking the row count?

Any other advice to reclaim unused disk space when the regular solutions don't fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB tablespace size for individual tables (`.ibd`) can be reduced with `OPTIMIZE` and `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;`, but the system tablespace file `ibdata1` can be never be shrunk.

The source of ibdata1's growth in in the undo logs.

[I have written posts about this since July 2013](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20uncontrolled). I first learned about this phenomenon from Percona's post [Reasons for run-away main Innodb Tablespace](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/06/10/reasons-for-run-away-main-innodb-tablespace/).

## Suggestion #1

If you mysqldump the data into another server running mysql in a newly installed instance, you could setup replication to it, then failover and trash the old master.

## Suggestion #2

If you do not have another server, you'll have stop the application, mysqldump the data, drop all DBs, shutdown mysql, delete ibdata1, start mysql (which recreates ibdata1, reload the mysqldump). See my very old post [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA. Can I get a bit more clarification around the first sentence? I understand that `.ibd`'s can be reduced with `OPTIMIZE` AND `ALTER`... But will MySQL ever recover some of the unallocated space within `.ibd` files? In the question above, the .ibd file grew from ~130GB to ~250GB. And even after removing the majority of excess rows, the `.ibd` size continues to grow. I'm curious why this is, and if MySQL will ever bring it back in line (without manually running an `OPTIMIZE` or `ALTER`).

Comment: InnoDB does not reclaim space for tablespace files (`.ibd` as well as `ibdata1`) When inserting new data, InnoDB will try to reuse fragmented space for new row data. Any space involved in your deletes is used for rollback purposes of all transaction include the rows being deleted. This is why `OPTIMIZE` and `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;` are often suggested.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE` and some variants of `ALTER` _rebuild_ the `.ibd` file.  _That_ is how the recover the space.  However, they need extra disk space during the process.

Comment: To add to @RickJames comment, for example: if you are rebuilding a 100GB table, there needs to be at least 100GB in disk space free.