# How to reduce the size of file in innodb_data_file_path (ibdata1) in mariadb without recreate db

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have db with `innodb` tables and use `innodb_file_per_table`

After

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `db`.`table`
```

of all tables the size of db on disk reduced (from 3.3G to 2.8G)

But size of file `ibdata1` is the same (270MB).

May be exists any third party solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does InnoDB ever release unused disk space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/does-innodb-ever-release-unused-disk-space)

Comment: After 4 years still didn't appear any third-party solution?

Comment: These sizes are tiny. Why is it important? There's an efficient implementation of *query time*, both insert/update and select, and means that a small amount of extra space is used because the cost of reducing this is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From MariaDB 11.2.0, when MariaDB starts up, unused InnoDB tablespace
> is reclaimed, reducing the file size (MDEV-14795).

> Furthermore, to avoid any bugs or extra overhead at startup related to
> this, it would be good to make this feature opt-in, that is, only
> attempt shrinking the system tablespace if innodb_data_file_path
> contains an extra attribute :autoshrink to enable the attempt.

Like `innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:1M:autoextend:autoshrink`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-tablespaces/#decreasing-the-size

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue [since 2003](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341) but without any solution to reduce the size of an InnoDB tablespace.

It applies to *any* InnoDB tablespace, not just ibdata1. What OPTIMIZE TABLE does is copy data to a *new* tablespace and drops the original tablespace. It does not shrink the existing tablespace.

The workaround, as you no doubt know, is to dump all your InnoDB tables, or else ALTER them to MyISAM temporarily, then shut down mysqld, reinitialize the ibdata1 file (just `rm ibdata` and the `iblog` files and any `.ibd` tablespace files), then start up mysqld, which will create a new ibdata1. Then reimport dumped data, or else ALTER tables from MyISAM back to InnoDB.

That is the unfortunate reality of InnoDB, and always has been.

Comment: Note MariaDB forked MyISAM to Aria a while ago, but same benefits as MyISAM in this answer, and some extra crash safety.

Comment: This question and answer is not about MyISAM or Aria.